# Value stored in array but not accessable?

Tags: ios, json, swift

i have sorted the web api which look like this and stored the value for key "attributevalue" in an array but while accessing it doesnot show up
any sugestion

```
{
  "responsemsg": "successfull",
  "responsecode": "200",
  "data": {
          "sku": "arv-95x103535",
           "description": "<p>watercolor on paper</p>\r\n",
           "shortdescription": "",
"prodattribute": [
  {
    "attrkeyvalue": "",
    "fk_CategoryId": 78,
    "colorimgpath": "",
    "attributevalue": "10",
    "lablename": " Height Inch",
    "fk_elementdetailid": 12,
    "IsRequired": true
  },
  {
    "attrkeyvalue": "",
    "fk_CategoryId": 78,
    "colorimgpath": "",
    "attributevalue": "9.5",
    "lablename": " Width Inch",
    "fk_elementdetailid": 13,
    "IsRequired": true
  },
  {
    "attrkeyvalue": "",
    "fk_CategoryId": 78,
    "colorimgpath": "",
    "attributevalue": "N.A",
    "lablename": " Year ",
    "fk_elementdetailid": 15,
    "IsRequired": true
  },
  {
    "attrkeyvalue": "",
    "fk_CategoryId": 78,
    "colorimgpath": "",
    "attributevalue": "Water color on paper",
    "lablename": " Medium ",
    "fk_elementdetailid": 16,
    "IsRequired": true
  },
  {
    "attrkeyvalue": "",
    "fk_CategoryId": 78,
    "colorimgpath": "",
    "attributevalue": "right bottom",
    "lablename": " Signature Position ",
    "fk_elementdetailid": 17,
    "IsRequired": true
  },
  {
    "attrkeyvalue": "",
    "fk_CategoryId": 78,
    "colorimgpath": "",
    "attributevalue": "Canvas",
    "lablename": " Surface ",
    "fk_elementdetailid": 19,
    "IsRequired": true
  }
]
```

this is my parsing code

```
   let jsonProductAttributes = jsonResult!["data"]!["prodattribute"] as! [AnyObject]
        print("The product Arrtibutes are",jsonProductAttributes)
        var artAttributesArry = [details]()
    for attri in jsonProductAttributes {
        let artDetails = details();
        artDetails.values = attri["attributevalue"]as! String
        artAttributesArry.append(artDetails)
   print("The attributed values are ",attri["attributevalue"]as! String)

    }
```

This is my model class

```
 class DetailProduct {
var attributes: [details]!

}

class details {
var values: String!
}
```

Any suggestion would be really helpful if their is any alteration or changes in codes

Thank you

Comment: What output do you get?  Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through your code to see what is happening?

Comment: Can you change prodattribute to be dictionary of dictionaries ?
"prodattribute": [
  [                      instead of {

Comment: Sir i have to access the ["prodattribute"]["attributevalue"] and show it on different label ..  so how to acheive that ?? any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is missing, at the end:

```
 }
}
```

The following I've tested with `Alamofire` and `SwiftyJSON`, works:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class APIWrapper {

    func getJSON() {

        print("Making request");
        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost:8000/swift") .responseJSON {
            (request, response, result) -> Void in

            if let value = result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                self.parseJSON(json)
            }
        }

    }

    func parseJSON(json: JSON) {

        for result in json["data"]["prodattribute"].arrayValue {
            print(result["attributevalue"].stringValue)
        }
    }
}
```

With the following JSON:

```
{
  "responsemsg": "successfull",
  "responsecode": "200",
  "data": {
          "sku": "arv-95x103535",
           "description": "<p>watercolor on paper</p>\r\n",
           "shortdescription": "",
"prodattribute": [
  {
    "attrkeyvalue": "",
    "fk_CategoryId": 78,
    "colorimgpath": "",
    "attributevalue": "10",
    "lablename": " Height Inch",
    "fk_elementdetailid": 12,
    "IsRequired": true
  },
  {
    "attrkeyvalue": "",
    "fk_CategoryId": 78,
    "colorimgpath": "",
    "attributevalue": "9.5",
    "lablename": " Width Inch",
    "fk_elementdetailid": 13,
    "IsRequired": true
  },
  {
    "attrkeyvalue": "",
    "fk_CategoryId": 78,
    "colorimgpath": "",
    "attributevalue": "N.A",
    "lablename": " Year ",
    "fk_elementdetailid": 15,
    "IsRequired": true
  },
  {
    "attrkeyvalue": "",
    "fk_CategoryId": 78,
    "colorimgpath": "",
    "attributevalue": "Water color on paper",
    "lablename": " Medium ",
    "fk_elementdetailid": 16,
    "IsRequired": true
  },
  {
    "attrkeyvalue": "",
    "fk_CategoryId": 78,
    "colorimgpath": "",
    "attributevalue": "right bottom",
    "lablename": " Signature Position ",
    "fk_elementdetailid": 17,
    "IsRequired": true
  },
  {
    "attrkeyvalue": "",
    "fk_CategoryId": 78,
    "colorimgpath": "",
    "attributevalue": "Canvas",
    "lablename": " Surface ",
    "fk_elementdetailid": 19,
    "IsRequired": true
  }
]
}
}
```

Comment: Sir i have to access the ["prodattribute"]["attributevalue"] and show it on different label ..  so how to acheive that ?? any help.

Comment: Instead of `print(result["attributevalue"].stringValue)` assign it to an array as you were doing in your code and use it elsewhere (to show on labels). Don't forget to mark the answer as correct.